# Can someone assist with my COUNTIF function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have included a picture of what my database looks like for reference.  This database tracks patients hemoglobin results and categorizes them into 3 different categories down at the bottom of the database.

I need the values in the E Column to be counted and sorted into the bottom categories.  Those formulas are as follows:

`=COUNTIFS(E2:E121,">=10",E2:E121,"<=12")`

`=COUNTIF(E2:E121,">12")`

`=COUNTIF(E2:E121,"<10")`

This seems to work fine.  Where I am getting caught up is that if there is also a value in the K Column (meaning we have drawn hemoglobin a second time) I need the formula to not include the result of the first draw (Column E) and instead include the result of the second draw (Column K).  The most recent Hemoglobin draws are the only ones I am interested in counting.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful.  Thank you!

I have been researching this issue and haven't come across anything helpful to me.  I am unsure if this is something that can even happen at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional column that says `=if(K2="",E2,K2)` then do the countifs off of that column (I'm assuming Col T):

`=COUNTIFS(T2:T121,">=10",T2:T121,"<=12")`

`=COUNTIF(T2:T121,">12")`

`=COUNTIF(T2:T121,"<10")`

Answer (score 0):

### Count Using `SUM(PRODUCT)`

[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(K$2:K$11="",(E$2:E$11>=10)*(E$2:E$11<=12),(K$2:K$11>=10)*(K$2:K$11<=12)))
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(IF(K$2:K$11="",E$2:E$11>12,K$2:K$11>12)))
```

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(IF(K$2:K$11="",E$2:E$11<10,K$2:K$11<10)))
```